# How to save many numpy arrays along with their names

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a few thousand numpy arrays with shape (14, 64, 1), which I create one by one.

As each one is created, I want to add it to a file (which I will eventually save), along with its name.

So the format would be:

```
[[[number, number....number, number]]] array_name_1
[[[number, number....number, number]]] array_name_2
.
.
[[[number, number....number, number]]] array_name_7012
```

What is the best way to do this? I usually save arrays using `numpy.savetxt` but I believe this only works for a two dimensional array.

Do I need to read everything into a numpy array first and then use something like numpy.save?

But if so, I know that numpy arrays support only one type of data in the array.

I'm looking for advice for the best way to get a file with the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several arrays can be saved into one `.npz` file.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html